# How do you copy multiple files using remote_src in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

When I run the command  remote_src: true I get the error
ERROR! 'remote_src' is not a valid attribute for a Task
I was wondering if there is a better way to write the code or if this is a bug

Tried to remove the offending line of code, however, the files exist on the remote host so I'm unable to copy the files into the correct location

```
- hosts: openvpn_server
  
  vars:
    file_vars:
     - { name: ca }
     - { name: server }
  
  tasks:

   - name: check if ca.crt and server.crt exists
     stat:
       path: /tmp/{{ item.name }}.crt
     with_items: "{{ file_vars }}"
     register: ensure_ca_crt_exists

   - name: copying server.crt and ca.crt
     become: true
     copy: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} 
     with_items:
      - { src: '/tmp/server.crt' , dest: '/etc/openvpn/server.crt' }
      - { src: '/tmp/ca.crt' , dest: '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt' } 
     remote_src: true


     when: ensure_ca_crt_exists.results
    
   - name: creating Diffie-Hellman key to use during key exchange
     shell: ./easyrsa gen-dh
     args:
      chdir: ~/EasyRSA-v3.0.6/
    
   - name: Generating HMAC signature to strengthen servers TLS integrity
     shell: openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
    
   - name: copying ta.key and dh.pem to /etc/openvpn
     become: true
     copy: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} 
     with_items:
       - { src: '/home/dc/EasyRSA-v3.0.6/ta.key' , dest: '/etc/openvpn/ta.key' }
       - { src: '/home/dc/EasyRSA-v3.0.6/dh.pem' , dest: '/etc/openvpn/dh.pem' }
```

I should be able to copy the file from the tmp folder to /etc/openvpn folder
via the remote_src command, apologizes for the badly configured register I'm fairly new to ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ERROR! 'remote_src' is not a valid attribute for a Task

Indentation is wrong

```
- name: copying server.crt and ca.crt
     become: true
     copy: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} 
     with_items:
      - { src: '/tmp/server.crt' , dest: '/etc/openvpn/server.crt' }
      - { src: '/tmp/ca.crt' , dest: '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt' } 
     remote_src: true
```

Correct

```
- name: copying server.crt and ca.crt
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
    remote_src: true
  loop:
    - {src: '/tmp/server.crt', dest: '/etc/openvpn/server.crt'}
    - {src: '/tmp/ca.crt', dest: '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'}
  become: true
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying some really good information there, once again thank you